# Map a set of types to unique IDs and runtime reinterpret back from ID and pointer in C++17

Tags: c++, design-patterns, template-meta-programming, c++17, rtti

I wanted to create a relatively universal way of serialising an object, by doing a `memcpy` and generating a unique type ID. Stored together they can be used, for example, by another thread to restore a copy of the object for further processing.

This is used, for example, where one tread has a logging function requiring minimal overhead and converting the object to its logged state is considerably more expensive than making a raw copy.

Some other requirements / design choices:

- IDs should be dense (no gaps)
- IDs should fit the smallest unsigned possible
- No RTTI allowed
- A slight convenience overhead at the runtime restoring side is acceptable (and present in the form of the generated 'if' tree to match an ID to a type)
- Both sides have access to the definition of the mapping
- Handling of constructors with side-effects is left up to the user

Id'd love to hear any critiques or possible pitfalls!
Below is the header pasted into a silly example to show the idea and interface:

```
// This keeps a variable in the final output:
#define KEEP(x) volatile auto x __attribute__((unused))

#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstddef>

namespace type_list {
        /**
     * @brief Extract the N-th type of a set of template arguments
     *
     * @tparam N    Index of type to extract
     * @tparam Ts   Arguments
     */
    template <std::size_t N, typename T, typename... Ts>
    struct nth_type {
        using type = typename nth_type<N-1, Ts...>::type;
    };

    template <typename T, typename... Ts>
    struct nth_type<0, T, Ts...> {
        using type = T;
    };

    /**
     * @brief Extract the N-th type of a set of template arguments
     *
     * @tparam N    Index of type to extract
     * @tparam Ts   Arguments
     */
    template <std::size_t N, typename... Ts>
    using nth_type_t = typename nth_type<N, Ts...>::type;

    /**
     * @brief Find the index of the first matching type `IN` in a set of types.
     *
     * @tparam IN   Type to find
     * @tparam T    First of type list
     * @tparam Ts   Rest of type list
     */
    template <typename IN, typename T, typename... Ts>
    struct index_of_type {
        static_assert(sizeof...(Ts) != 0 || std::is_same_v<IN, T>, "No index for type found");
        static constexpr const std::size_t value { 1 + index_of_type<IN, Ts...>::value };
    };

    template <typename IN, typename... Ts>
    struct index_of_type<IN, IN, Ts...> {
        static constexpr const std::size_t value { 0 };
    };

    /**
     * @brief Find the index of the first matching type `IN` in a set of types.
     *
     * @tparam IN   Type to find
     * @tparam Ts   Type list
     */
    template <typename IN, typename... Ts>
    static constexpr const auto index_of_type_v { index_of_type<IN, Ts...>::value };

    namespace {
        static constexpr void noop(const std::size_t = 0) {}

        template <size_t I, typename... Ts>
        struct map_visit_impl {
            template <typename F, typename E>
            static constexpr decltype(auto) visit(const std::size_t id, const void *const ptr, F func, E on_error) {
                if (id == I - 1) {
                    return func(*reinterpret_cast<const nth_type_t<I-1, Ts...> *const>(ptr));
                } else {
                    return map_visit_impl<I - 1, Ts...>::visit(id, ptr, func, on_error);
                }
            }

            template <typename F, typename E>
            static constexpr decltype(auto) visit(const std::size_t id, void *const ptr, F func, E on_error) {
                if (id == I - 1) {
                    return func(*reinterpret_cast<nth_type_t<I-1, Ts...> *const>(ptr));
                } else {
                    return map_visit_impl<I - 1, Ts...>::visit(id, ptr, func, on_error);
                }
            }
        };

        template <typename... Ts>
        struct map_visit_impl<0, Ts...> {
            template <typename F, typename E>
            static constexpr void visit(const std::size_t id, const void *const, F func, E on_error) {
                // If arrived here we have a invalid id
                on_error(id);
            }

            template <typename F, typename E>
            static constexpr void visit(const std::size_t id, void *const, F func, E on_error) {
                // If arrived here we have a invalid id
                on_error(id);
            }
        };
    }

    /**
     * @brief Create an ID map of a set of types.
     *
     * @tparam Ts Type list
     */
    template <typename... Ts>
    struct map {
        /**
         * @brief Get the type with index `N`
         *
         * @tparam N Index of type to get
         */
        template <std::size_t N>
        using type = type_list::nth_type_t<N, Ts...>;

        /**
         * @brief The ID number (index) of a given type `T`
         *
         * @tparam T
         */
        template <typename T>
        static constexpr const std::size_t id { type_list::index_of_type_v<T, Ts...> };

        /**
         * @brief Number of types stored
         */
        static constexpr const std::size_t size { sizeof...(Ts) };

        /**
         * @brief Convert any given pointer to the type matching `id` and pass
         * it to a function `func` as only argument using a `reinterpret_cast`.
         *
         * @tparam F    Function type
         * @param id    id / index of type
         * @param ptr   Storage location
         * @param func  Handler function
         * @return      Result of handler function
         */
        template <typename F, typename E = decltype(noop)>
        static constexpr decltype(auto) parse(const std::size_t id, const void *const ptr, F func, E on_error = noop) {
            return map_visit_impl<sizeof...(Ts), Ts...>::visit(id, ptr, func, on_error);
        }

        /**
         * @brief Convert any given pointer to the type matching `id` and pass
         * it to a function `func` as only argument using a `reinterpret_cast`.
         *
         * @tparam F    Function type
         * @param id    id / index of type
         * @param ptr   Storage location
         * @param func  Handler function
         * @return      Result of handler function
         */
        template <typename F, typename E = decltype(noop)>
        static constexpr decltype(auto) parse(const std::size_t id, void *const ptr, F func, E on_error = noop) {
            return map_visit_impl<sizeof...(Ts), Ts...>::visit(id, ptr, func, on_error);
        }
    };
}

// Generate unique types
template <size_t N> struct c {};

// Demo set of types
using map = type_list::map<
    uint8_t, uint16_t, uint32_t, int8_t, int16_t, int32_t,
    c<__COUNTER__>, c<__COUNTER__>, c<__COUNTER__>, c<__COUNTER__>,
    c<__COUNTER__>, c<__COUNTER__>, c<__COUNTER__>, c<__COUNTER__>,
    c<__COUNTER__>, c<__COUNTER__>, c<__COUNTER__>, c<__COUNTER__>,
    c<__COUNTER__>, c<__COUNTER__>, c<__COUNTER__>, c<__COUNTER__>,
    c<__COUNTER__>, c<__COUNTER__>, c<__COUNTER__>, c<__COUNTER__>,
    c<__COUNTER__>, c<__COUNTER__>, c<__COUNTER__>, c<__COUNTER__>,
    c<__COUNTER__>, c<__COUNTER__>, c<__COUNTER__>, c<__COUNTER__>,
    c<__COUNTER__>, c<__COUNTER__>, c<__COUNTER__>, c<__COUNTER__>,
    c<__COUNTER__>, c<__COUNTER__>, c<__COUNTER__>, c<__COUNTER__>,
    c<__COUNTER__>, c<__COUNTER__>, c<__COUNTER__>, c<__COUNTER__>
>;

// Just a quick hack to initialise some test data:
char bytes[] = "Test string, bla bla";

uint64_t counter = 0;

void fn(const std::size_t n, const std::size_t i) {
    __asm volatile("# LLVM-MCA-BEGIN type_map_overhead");
    map::parse(n, &bytes[i], [&](auto& val) {
        __asm volatile("# LLVM-MCA-END");
        // Needed because the handler needs to apply to any type in the map:
        if constexpr (std::is_integral_v<decltype(val)>) {
            counter += val;
        }
    });
}

int main() {
    KEEP(k1) = map::id<uint16_t>; // size_t => 1
    KEEP(k2) = std::is_same_v<map::type<1>, uint16_t>; // bool => true

    fn(0, 0);
    fn(1, 1);
    fn(2, 2);

    KEEP(k4) = counter;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be nice to pass a size with the buffer, so we can check the size of the type vs the size of the buffer. Also, a pointer to `unsigned char` or [`std::byte`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/byte) would be better than a `void*`.

I think using [`reinterpret_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) like this is undefined behaviour. We can copy the object representation (by `reinterpret_cast`ing to `char` or `unsigned char` and copying manually, or using `std::memcpy`). However, the object may have alignment requirements or padding that aren't observable in this representation.

Since the character array was created as a character array, it doesn't have the necessary alignment / padding, so using it directly as if it were the object is undefined behaviour. We have to use `std::memcpy` to copy the bytes back into memory that was actually allocated as the object in question.

Note that [`std::memcpy` has requirements of its own](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy). Specifically that types be [`TriviallyCopyable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/TriviallyCopyable), so constructors with side-effects will not work. It would be good to check this when serializing the object with a `static_assert(is_trivially_copyable_v<T>, "...")`.

Comment: I disagree on `void*` versus `unsigned char*` or `byte*`. I think `void*` is absolutely the right type to semantically represent "pointer to a thing I don't know what it is." In fact, if you use `void*` (as OP did), then you don't need the `reinterpret_cast`; you can just use a less-scary-looking `static_cast` (as OP didn't). If you pretend that your pointer points to `unsigned char`, or pretend that it points to `byte`, then you're lying to the compiler, and so you _would_ need the `reinterpret_cast` to undo the lie.

Comment: @Quuxplusone Hmm. I would agree, except that OP mentions using `memcpy` to serialise the object. So I think it actually is an array of bytes, not a pointer to an object.

Comment: Yeah, as you mention, OP's code has alignment issues and also requires trivial copyability for `T`. But I think that's all kind of orthogonal. If the alignment issues were fixed, then I stand by my claim that `void*` would be more "right" than `unsigned char*`. If the alignment issues _aren't_ fixed, then it doesn't matter because nothing is right because the code doesn't even work. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
// This keeps a variable in the final output:
#define KEEP(x) volatile auto x __attribute__((unused))
```

Getting off to a controversial start here, aren't we? :)  This macro is used *only* in your test harness `main()`, so it should be defined way down at the bottom of the file, right above `main()`. That way the reader doesn't get scared that your actual library functionality requires such a wacky macro.

In general, you should make it clearer which part of your code is the library and which part is the test harness. Consider adding `#ifdef TESTING` around the harness code, which, IIUC, basically begins at the line

```
// Generate unique types
```

---

If *all* you're using `KEEP` for is to "keep a variable in the final output," why don't you just make the variable global? That is, replace

```
int main() {
    KEEP(k1) = map::id<uint16_t>; // size_t => 1
    KEEP(k2) = std::is_same_v<map::type<1>, uint16_t>; // bool => true

    fn(0, 0);
    fn(1, 1);
    fn(2, 2);

    KEEP(k4) = counter;
}
```

with simply

```
size_t k1 = map::id<uint16_t>;  // should be 1
bool k2 = std::is_same_v<map::type<1>, uint16_t>;  // should be true
size_t k4 = 0;

int main() {
    fn(0, 0);
    fn(1, 1);
    fn(2, 2);

    k4 = counter;  // should be ???
}
```

Since other translation units might access `k1`, `k2`, and `k4` by name, the compiler *has* to keep them around. No `volatile` or `__attribute__` needed!

---

```
void fn(const std::size_t n, const std::size_t i) {
```

Lose the meaningless `const`s. They just make your function prototype harder to read. (Personally, I would also lose the `std::`s; they aren't needed. But some people like them, and if you're such a person, I won't argue.)

```
void fn(size_t n, size_t i) {
```

So much cleaner! Now we even have room to give `n` and `i` real names, if we want to.

---

FWIW, I don't understand the purpose of the `__asm volatile` comments.

---

```
map::parse(n, &bytes[i], [&](auto& val) {
    __asm volatile("# LLVM-MCA-END");
    // Needed because the handler needs to apply to any type in the map:
    if constexpr (std::is_integral_v<decltype(val)>) {
        counter += val;
    }
});
```

It is highly unusual to write a generic lambda that takes a parameter of type `auto&`.  Pass-by-value `auto`, sure. Pass-by-forwarding-reference `auto&&`, sure. Pass-by-const-ref `const auto&`, quite plausibly. But pass-by-nonconst-ref `auto&`? That's a weird one. Are you sure that's what you want? In generic code you usually want `auto&&` for perfect forwarding.

Since `decltype(val)` is *always* a reference type, it's *never* an integral type. Do you observe this `if constexpr` branch ever being taken? I don't think it is being taken. What was its purpose supposed to be?

---

```
static constexpr void noop(const std::size_t = 0) {}
```

What is the purpose of the default function argument here? I would prefer to see this as

```
static void noop(size_t) {}
```

or, even better if you care about inlining,

```
struct Noop { void operator()(size_t) const {} };
```

And then down where you use `noop`:

```
template <typename F, typename E = decltype(noop)>
static constexpr decltype(auto) parse(const std::size_t id, const void *const ptr, F func, E on_error = noop) {
    return map_visit_impl<sizeof...(Ts), Ts...>::visit(id, ptr, func, on_error);
}
```

this would be better optimizable if you wrote it as

```
template<class F, class E = Noop>
static constexpr decltype(auto) parse(size_t id, const void *ptr, F func, E on_error = E()) {
    return map_visit_impl<sizeof...(Ts), Ts...>::visit(id, ptr, func, on_error);
}
```

And if you *really* care about efficiency, and don't want to burden your end-user with wrapping their error handler in `std::ref()` all the time, then you'll break with STL tradition and either pass the error handler by reference, or move-out-of it (instead of copying it) when you pass it by value:

```
template<class F, class E = Noop>
static constexpr decltype(auto) parse(size_t id, const void *ptr, const F& func, const E& on_error = E()) {
    return map_visit_impl<sizeof...(Ts), Ts...>::visit(id, ptr, func, on_error);
}
```

or

```
template<class F, class E = Noop>
static constexpr decltype(auto) parse(size_t id, const void *ptr, F func, E on_error = E()) {
    return map_visit_impl<sizeof...(Ts), Ts...>::visit(id, ptr, std::move(func), std::move(on_error));
}
```

---

```
template <typename IN, typename... Ts>
static constexpr const auto index_of_type_v { index_of_type<IN, Ts...>::value };
```

This is the weirdest way of writing

```
template<class T, class... Ts>
inline constexpr size_t index_of_type_v = index_of_type<T, Ts...>::value;
```

that I've ever seen. :)

---

```
    /*
     * @tparam F    Function type
     * @param id    id / index of type
     * @param ptr   Storage location
     * @param func  Handler function
     * @return      Result of handler function
```

You know, if you renamed `ptr` to `storage` and renamed `func` to `handler`, then you could get rid of this comment. (Self-documenting code!)

---

```
return func(*reinterpret_cast<const nth_type_t<I-1, Ts...> *const>(ptr));
```

As I mentioned in a comment on [user673679's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/210687/16369), you should avoid `reinterpret_cast` whenever possible. It's a big red flag that makes the reader wonder what trickery you're doing. So, if you're not doing any trickery, you should avoid waving that red flag unnecessarily.

Also, as usual, you've got useless `const`s that merely clutter the code.

```
return func(*static_cast<const nth_type_t<I-1, Ts...> *>(ptr));
```

---

Both `index_of_type` and `map_visit_impl` are done with recursive template instantiations. You should consider how to rewrite them as non-recursive templates using pack expansion and/or fold-expressions. Especially `map_visit_impl`, since function instantiation is basically the slowest thing you can ask a compiler to do. See [this blog post](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2018/07/23/metafilter/) for inspiration if you need it.

Comment: I feel like I need to review the answer, you bring up some very valid points, thanks for that, but also some things that are plain wrong. The macro is obviously just part of the test harness, by convention put on top to prevent changing the meaning of code halfway through the translation unit. Without the 'whacky' macro you have to rewrite everything as global, which is doable for a small main, but certainly not great if you want to selectively 'probe' a few variables in assembly. Only in testing, as you rightly point out.

Comment: `size_t` is not standard C++, `std::size` is, you're proposing to make the code less portable. Interestingly, this is often pointed out in reviews here. Same for `const` correctness. Less is not more here and your advice would lead to worse code.

Comment: The MCA comments are to allow `llvm-mca`, the [LLVM Machine Code Analyser](https://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/llvm-mca.html) to understand that this code section is to be analysed separately. It's a pretty neat tool, [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/) has it built-in these days.

Comment: Good point about the reference in the universal lambda, I will improve that. I was doubting about allowing write access at all. I added the `if constexpr` integral check for the specific test scenario (to filter out the classes), I'll verify its workings.

Comment: About the restructuring of the way the error handler is attached. About the error function itself: What if I pass a const size_t to your proposed version? I wonder how much of your structural optimisation is needed to just compensate for your preference to not use `const` and `constexpr`. GCC certainly likes `constexpr` functions for inlining. I'll make a version as you proposed to see if it makes a difference in resulting assembly.

Comment: _What if I pass a `const size_t`_ ... _`const` correctness. Less is not more here_ ... It sounds like you don't understand the notion of const-correctness in C++, or at least you have some misconception about the meaning of pass-by-`const`-value in a function signature. I want to say that googling "const is a contract" should clear up the misconception, but actually I'm not pleased with the top search results there. ([The Const Nazi](http://gamesfromwithin.com/the-const-nazi) is actually the best search result so far.) I guess I have another blog post to write soon... :)

Comment: Let's go over `static constexpr const auto ... {}` vs `inline constexpr size_t ... =` : `static` in this case is to take a more prudent default: any translation unit using the template will not by default pollute the global namespace. `constexpr` implies `inline`, so it's not needed to add this. I prefer `auto` because it reduces information duplication, reducing issues with future code changes. For the difference between direct initialisation (`{}`) and assignment initialisation read up if you like, but in practice I've not seen differences in generated code.

Comment: _`constexpr` implies `inline`_ — No it doesn't. [Wandbox example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/bhaYGS872vRVwh3h). When in doubt, do as the STL does: [`inline constexpr [type]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same#Helper_variable_template). They do have a reason for picking that exact sequence of keywords. :)

Comment: _I guess I have another blog post to write soon..._ [The blog post has now been written!](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2019/01/03/const-is-a-contract/)